# Assumptions of weighted least squares regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, least-squares, assumptions

I have built a weighted least squares regression model and was about to interpret the results. But before doing that, I wanted to check for assumptions first. However, I couldn't find the assumptions of weighted least squares anywhere. I was going to check for the assumptions of ordinary least squares but because these two models are completely different, I didn't do it.

What are the assumptions of weighted least squares regression?

Comment: if by WLS, you are weighting the diagonals of the covariance matrix by the inverse of the $predictor^2$, then the assumptions are the same as OLS except that $\sigma^2_{i} $ is proportional to $\sigma^2 x_{i}^2$.

Comment: I used the inverse of residuals^2. Does this mean the assumptions are the same?

Comment: hopefully someone else can comment because it's been too long since I looked at this material but I don't think you should use the residuals because you don't know what they are beforehand.

Comment: I built a multiple variable model, so I had to use the residuals.

Comment: Hi: This question is really outside my field ( maybe someone else can help ) so  I would check out the literature on how to do WLS in a multiple regression model. The residuals are only available after the regression is estimated so are you using 2 steps ?

Comment: Hi: I don't have time to look at it in detail but the second example in this link gives the steps for doing WLS when there is more than one predictor variable. Hopefully it can provide some useful insight.  https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/186/

Comment: Note that, in regard to your original question, the assumptions are be the same as those in OLS except that OLS assumes constant variance of the error term  and WLS doesn't.